# Exporting Scrapy items with Selenium scraped content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website using Scrapy and Selenium, and everything works just fine except the "yield item" part of the code.

In the "def parse_product(self, response)" part, I'm using Selenium find_element_by_css_selector to fill a list and then use the "for element in zip(list1, list2, etc)" approach to generate my items. I have also set up a Pipeline to export the result into a csv.

The problem is that although my spider is scraping the objects correctly (I have tested it with some prints along the way), the item creation part is not working and I'm getting an empty csv.

I have tried another approach that works, but is too slow. It consists in defining a Middleware to pass the request through Selenium, load the page source code and return a HtmlResponse. Then, I just simply use the response.css() method to fill the lists, the same approach to generate the items and the same Pipeline to export it as csv.

**spider.py**

```
def __init__(self):
    #Headless Option
    opt = Options()
    opt.headless = True

    ## get the Firefox profile object
    prf = FirefoxProfile()
    ## Disable CSS
    prf.set_preference('permissions.default.stylesheet', 2)
    ## Disable images
    prf.set_preference('permissions.default.image', 2)

    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options = opt, firefox_profile = prf)

def parse(self, response):
    self.browser.get(response.url)
    print('Current URL: ' + response.request.url)

    # Find the total number of pages

    # Go to last page (click on '>>')
    self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.ais-pagination__item:nth-child(9) a:nth-child(1)').click()

    n = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.ais-pagination__item:nth-child(7) a:nth-child(1)').get_attribute('text')
    pages = int(n.strip())

    # Go back to first page (click on '<<')
    self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.ais-pagination__item:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(1)').click()

    # Scrape product links
    pdcts = []
    href = []
    i=1
    while i<=n:

        # Append Product Links
        atag = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class*="ph-proucts"] a')
        for a in atag:
            href.append(a.get_attribute('href'))

        prd = list(set(href))

        for p in prd:
            pdcts.append(p)

        # Load new page of products (Click '>')
        self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('li.ais-pagination__item:nth-child(8) a:nth-child(1)').click()

        i+=1

    for link in pdcts:
        yield scrapy.Request(url = link, callback = self.parse_product)

def parse_product(self, response):
    self.browser.get(response.url)
    print("Current URL: " + response.request.url)

    #Item Initializator
    name = []

    #Item Filling
    try:
        n = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="flex xs12 sm12 md12"] h1').text
        name.append(string.capwords(n))
    except:
        n1 = response.request.url
        n = n1.split('products/')[1].replace('-',' ')
        name.append(string.capwords(n))       

    #Item Creation
    for i in zip(name):
        self.browser.quit()

        item = ProjectItem()

        item['name'] = i[0]

        yield item
```

The expected result is a csv with the scraped information but I'm getting an empty one instead.

Could anyone help me with this please? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Can i get the application url?

Comment: is very similar to this excercise, but inside a Scrapy Spider: https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-web-scraping-with-pythons-selenium-4cedc52798cd

Comment: Solved the problem, instead of typing "for i in zip(a,b,c)" it should be "for i in list(zip(a,b,c))"